# Can't see certain characters in Chrome (yes I searched, results didn't work)

Tags: google-chrome, unicode, encoding, fonts

So I found [this site](http://www.panix.com/~eli/unicode/convert.cgi?text=The%20quick%20brown%20fox%20jumps%20over%20the%20lazy%20dog) to make some silly text. I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ8V3.png). Now I have a bunch of fonts installed that should allow me to see this (DeJaVu, Arial Unicode, Quivira, etc) and I tried various encoders too. I have no issues in Firefox and Chrome works on my MacBook but on my Windows 8.1 PC it just won't show. I am able to see this thing: » which some people have trouble seeing. And I tried incognito and still not working. Am I doing something wrong or what?

Comment: > I have no issues in Firefox and Chrome works on my MacBook
So, yes as I mentioned in the post


>I have a bunch of fonts installed that should allow me to see this (DeJaVu, Arial Unicode, Quivira, etc)

Again, yes as I mentioned in the post

Comment: firefox on windows, chrome on mac

Comment: Try other browser, does IE work?

Comment: I dont have it installed

Comment: Try another browser and see if it works. Did you uninstall IE? It's installed by default...

Comment: i didnt uninstall it but i cant find it. doesnt show up in start menu search bar

Comment: ok the website works in IE and firefox and not opera or chrome

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the font Code2000?  If that doesn't work with Chrome, try Code2000 in the newest IE (where I confirmed it work).